# declaration error: identifier not found or not unique

Tags: java, solidity

My code is

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

pragma solidity >=0.8.17 <0.9.0;

contract bachi is ERC721, Ownable {

    using strings for uint256;

    uint256 public constant MAX_TOKENS = 999;
    uint256 private constant TOKENS_RESERVED = 5;
    uint256 public price = 9000000000000000;
    uint256 public constant MAX_MINT_PER_TX = 2;

    bool public isSaleActive;
    uint256 public totalsupply;
    mapping(address => uint256) private mintedperwallet;

    string public baseuri;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";

    constructor() ERC721("bachi", "bac") {
        // Base IPFS URI of the NFTS
        baseuri = "ipfs://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= TOKENS_RESERVED; ++i) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, i);
        }
        totalsupply = TOKENS_RESERVED;
```

The problem is in using strings for uint256.

I have created the file name and the contract name same, but then also it is same error. Please give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove one of two statement related to compiler version (`pragma solidity` ..). Then you have to include Strings.sol smart contract created for OpenZeppelin for using [Strings](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Strings.sol) smart contract.

I modified your original smart contract in this way:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";

contract bachi is ERC721, Ownable {
    using Strings for uint256;

    uint256 public constant MAX_TOKENS = 999;
    uint256 private constant TOKENS_RESERVED = 5;
    uint256 public price = 9000000000000000;
    uint256 public constant MAX_MINT_PER_TX = 2;

    bool public isSaleActive;
    uint256 public totalsupply;
    mapping(address => uint256) private mintedperwallet;

    string public baseuri;
    string public baseExtension = ".json";

    constructor() ERC721("bachi", "bac") {
        // Base IPFS URI of the NFTS
        baseuri = "ipfs://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/";
        for (uint256 i = 1; i <= TOKENS_RESERVED; ++i) {
            _safeMint(msg.sender, i);
        }
        totalsupply = TOKENS_RESERVED;
    }
}
```